# C programming - Reading data from file and storing it in a linked list

Tags: c

I am currently writing a program which reads a file, line by line, and stores the data contained in each line in a linked list. The only problem I am having is that each node in the linked list is being set to the data contained on the last line of the file. Could anybody please help me out? My code is shown below.

```
void calcFile( char sourceFile[] )
{
     int valid;

     FILE* f;

     int done;

     char buff[12];
     LinkedList* list = NULL;
     list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

     done = 1;
     f = fopen( sourceFile, "rb" );
     if (f != NULL)
     {
         do
         {
             if (fgets(buff, 12, f) != NULL)
             {
                 char* storageArray[2];
                 valid = lineCalc( buff, storageArray );
                 if (valid == 1)
                 {
                     LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
                     newNode->command = storageArray[0];
                     newNode->value = storageArray[1];
                     newNode->next = list->head;
                     list->head = newNode;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 done = 0;
             }
         }
         while (done != 0);
         if (ferror( f ) != 0)
         {
             printf("\n Error - the source file could not be read \n\n");
         }
         fclose( f );
     }
     else
     {
         printf("\n Error - the file could not be opened \n\n");
     }
     list->head = reverseLinkedList( list->head );
     linkedListCalc( list->head );
     freeLinkedList( list->head );
     free( list );
 }
```

Comment: Remove the line numbers and provide a [mcve]

Comment: This problem is so common that without looking at your code I guess you don't copy the data from each line to somewhere else. So all nodes point to the same (most recent) data.

Comment: What does `lineCalc( buff, storageArray );` do?

Comment: sagi - lineCalc splits the line from the file into 2 parts. The first part (command) is stored in storageArray[0], the second part (value) is stored in storageArray[1].

Comment: We don't see your `struct` definition, but `newNode->command = storageArray[0]; newNode->value = storageArray[1];` do not copy a string: only a pointer, so the nodes *do* all point to the same (most recent) data.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not posted `lineCalc()`, I cannot be sure. But I think you have a code similar to the following:

```
int lineCalc(char* buf, char** storage)
{
    if (strlen(buf) < 6)
        return -1;

    storage[0] = buf[0];
    storage[1] = buf[5];
    return 0;
}
```

If you have something like this, this will be your problem. Because `storage` points to `buf` directly, so every time that you read new content, all nodes will point to similar data. If you have something like this, allocate memory for each `storage` index and copy data from `buf` into it.